# WithUrl() not found in Core 3 client

Tags: wpf, .net-core, signalr

My .NET SignalR client code not working any more in Core 3 (WPF):

```
string hubAddress = "https://localhost:44329/Hub";
HubConnection hub = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl(hubAddress).Build(); // WithUrl not found
```

[MS document said it is there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/dotnet-client?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: `WithUrl()` is an extension method. Do you have `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client;` in your C# file?

Comment: When I ran the package import from the quick fix menu it got the wrong one (in VS2019). I think it was the "AspNet.SignalR.Client". I had to remove that one and get the correct "AspNetCore…".

Answer (score 75):

Found a [solution](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/5137):  make sure project referencing **Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client**, but not Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.Core.

Comment: This fixed my issue. It's hilarious that Microsoft makes the libraries so inconsistent.

Comment: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.Core depends on Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client so you have to have both installed in the project.

Comment: @LeszekJezierski It's the other way round - The Client depends on Core. So you just have to reference Client and Core will be brought in. Client has the .WithUrl required.

Answer (score 18):

Remove the dependency `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.Core` from your app and then add

Using Package Manager Console

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client -Version 6.0.0
```

Using .Net CLI

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client --version 6.0.0
```

It will fix your issue